# Example script for teaching DDL and CRUD/DML operations

Tags: beginner, sql, sql-server, database, crud

I have taught some SQL to others before, and I thought of making a script that has these attributes, for the purposes of teaching:

- Fully functional to run on local DB instance with no fuss
- Easy to follow along
- Representative examples of real-life types of operations
- Documented

The example first goes over some [Data Definition Language (DDL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848799.aspx) operations, including initializing a database and schema, creating tables with various data types, and creating a few simple triggers.

Then it covers fundamental [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) (or [Data Manipulation Language (DDL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848766.aspx)) operations.

I would like to know, first of all, am I doing things optimally from a SQL standpoint? I want to make sure I am not accidentally teaching bad habits.

Besides that, do you think this could be improved from a teaching standpoint to make it easier or more clear to a beginner who is interested in learning SQL?

Here is the query:

```
/* Initialize by deleting the database if it already exists, then creating the database: */
use master;
go
if exists (select name from master.dbo.sysdatabases where name = 'ACME_MFG_CO')
    drop database ACME_MFG_CO;
go
create database ACME_MFG_CO;
go
/* Switch to our new database, so we can perform operations on it: */
use ACME_MFG_CO;
go
/* Initialize by deleting the schema if it already exists, then creating the schema:  */
if (select 1 from sys.schemas where name = 'PRODUCTS') is not null
    drop schema PRODUCTS;
go
create schema PRODUCTS;
go

/***** Data Definition Language (DDL) operations *****/

/* The OBJECT_ID built-in function makes the DB engine check system objects by their name as string
 *   and returns the OBJECT_ID, if found, otherwise null. The following commands will check if
 *   the temporary tables we are about to create already exist, and if they do, they will be dropped/deleted. */
if object_id('ACME_MFG_CO.PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_CATALOG') is not null drop table ACME_MFG_CO.PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_CATALOG;
if object_id('ACME_MFG_CO.PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_DEVELOPMENT') is not null drop table ACME_MFG_CO.PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_DEVELOPMENT;
go

/* We create two tables which we will use throughout the examples in this script: */
create table PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_CATALOG 
(
  pc_id int identity(1,1),
  /* Empty string if product code not provided, since we cannot use a nullable field as part of the PRIMARY KEY: */
  pc_code varchar(50) not null default '', 
  pc_name varchar(200) not null,
  /* In this case it is preferable to have a value stating that there is no description, rather than an empty field
   *   (for example to be displayed to users in a web page or application): */
  pc_description varchar(max) default 'No description found.',
  pc_active bit,
  /* Product will be marked as discontinued = FALSE by default, since we rarely will be adding discontinued products to the catalog: */
  pc_discontinued bit default 0,
  /* Default to null as the MFG Cost might not be known yet when product is first added: */
  pc_mfgcost decimal(12,4) null default null,
  /* Default to null as the Retail Price might not be decided yet when product is first added: */
  pc_retailprice decimal(12,4) null default null,
  pc_insertdate datetime not null default getdate(),
  /* Unless specified otherwise this defaults to the user name/ID of the SPID that executes the insert: */
  pc_insertedby varchar(100) not null default CURRENT_USER,
  /* This will be updated via a trigger on record updates: */
  pc_lastupdate datetime,
  pc_lastupdatedby varchar(100),
  /* Unique binary ID */
  pc_uniqueid uniqueidentifier default newid(),
  primary key (pc_id, pc_code, pc_name, pc_uniqueid),
  unique (pc_code, pc_name)
);
go
create table PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_DEVELOPMENT 
(
    pd_id int identity(1,1),
    pd_name varchar(200) not null,
    pd_goal varchar(max) not null,
    pd_engineer varchar(200),
    pd_marketingcontact varchar(200),
    pd_devcompletedate datetime,
    pd_insertdate datetime default getdate(),
    /* This will be updated via a trigger on record updates: */
    pd_lastupdate datetime,
    pd_lastupdatedby varchar(100),
    pd_uniqueid uniqueidentifier default newid(),
    primary key (pd_id, pd_name, pd_uniqueid),
    unique (pd_name)
);
go
create trigger PRODUCTS.tr_PRODUCT_CATALOG_update
on PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_CATALOG
for update as
begin;
    update pc
    set pc_lastupdate = getdate(),
        pc_lastupdatedby = CURRENT_USER
    from PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_CATALOG as pc
    inner join inserted as i 
        on pc.pc_uniqueid = i.pc_uniqueid;
end;
go
create trigger PRODUCTS.tr_PRODUCT_DEVELOPMENT_update
    on PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_DEVELOPMENT
    for update 
as
begin;
    update pd
    set pd_lastupdate = getdate(),
        pd_lastupdatedby = CURRENT_USER
    from PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_DEVELOPMENT as pd
    inner join inserted as i 
        on pd.pd_uniqueid = i.pd_uniqueid;
end;
go

/***** Data Manipulation Language (DML) operations *****/

/*Add existing catalog products:*/
begin transaction;
insert into PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_CATALOG
  (pc_code, pc_name, pc_description, pc_active, pc_discontinued, pc_mfgcost, pc_retailprice) 
values
  ('ABC-123', 'Foo Product', 'Our customers'' favorite!', 1, 0, 42.1234, 89.99),
  ('DEF-345', 'Bar Product', 'A low-fat alternative to Foo Product!', 1, 0, 45.6789, 95.99),
  ('XYZ-987', 'Awful Product', 'This was a terrible idea.', 1, 0, 741.4555, 299.99);
commit transaction;

select * from PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_CATALOG;

/*Add a new product to development with basic information:*/
begin transaction;
insert into PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_DEVELOPMENT
  (pd_name, pd_goal, pd_engineer, pd_marketingcontact, pd_insertdate, pd_lastupdate)
select
    [pd_name] = 'FooBaz Product-DEV', 
    [pd_goal] = 'To make an upgraded version of Foo Product with added features X and Y.', 
    [pd_engineer] = 'Harold E., PHD',
    [pd_marketingcontact] = 'Maria M., VP Sales',
    [pd_insertdate] = dateadd(month, -2, getdate()), --inserted 2 months ago
    [pd_lastupdate] = dateadd( day, -4, dateadd(week, -3, getdate()) ); --updated 3 weeks and 4 days ago (two separate operations)
commit transaction;

select * from PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_DEVELOPMENT;

/*Mark dev completed and add the product from dev to catalog:*/
begin transaction;
declare @targetProduct varchar(200) = 'FooBaz Product-DEV';
if not exists (
    select 1 from PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_CATALOG as pc
    inner join PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_DEVELOPMENT as pd 
      on pc.pc_uniqueid = pd.pd_uniqueid 
    where pd.pd_name = @targetProduct
)
begin;
    update PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_DEVELOPMENT set pd_devcompletedate = getdate() where pd_name = @targetProduct;
    insert into PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_CATALOG 
        (pc_name, pc_insertedby, pc_uniqueid)
    select 
        replace(pd_name, '-DEV', ''), --remove the '-DEV' marker from name
        pd_marketingcontact, 
        pd_uniqueid
    from PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_DEVELOPMENT
    where pd_name = @targetProduct;
    commit transaction;
end;
else 
begin; 
    select 'Product ' + @targetProduct + ' already exists in PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_CATALOG' as [NOTICE];
    print 'Product ' + @targetProduct + ' already exists in PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_CATALOG';
    rollback transaction;
end;

select * 
from PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_CATALOG as pc 
left join PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_DEVELOPMENT as pd on pc.pc_uniqueid = pd.pd_uniqueid;

/*Later on, update the new product with more information:*/
begin transaction;
update PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_CATALOG
set
  pc_code = 'GHJ-789',
  pc_name = 'FooBaz Product',
  pc_description = 'Our newest product in the FooBar series!',
  pc_active = 1,
  pc_mfgcost = 97.9876,
  pc_retailprice = 139.99
where pc_name = 'FooBaz Product';
commit transaction;

select * from PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_CATALOG order by pc_lastupdate desc;

/*Inactivate and discontinue unprofitable products:*/
begin transaction;
update PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_CATALOG
set pc_active = 0, pc_discontinued = 1
where pc_mfgcost > pc_retailprice;
commit transaction;

select * from PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_CATALOG order by pc_lastupdate desc;

/*Some application user playing a joke on us...*/
begin transaction;
insert into PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_CATALOG 
    (pc_code, pc_name, pc_description, pc_insertedby) 
values
    ('HAHAHAHA', 'GARBAGE!!', 'Eat my shorts.', 'ApplicationLoginSession\20151110\JoeSpammer');
commit transaction;

select * from PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_CATALOG order by pc_insertdate desc;

/*Our application admins blocked their account, now let's clean up after this spammer:*/
begin transaction;
delete from PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_CATALOG
where pc_insertedby like '%\JoeSpammer'; --using the % wildcard in place of any number of any characters before the user name
commit transaction;

select * from PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_CATALOG order by pc_insertdate desc;
```

After the whole query is executed (takes approximately 1-2 seconds) it displays the 7 individual result sets that show the various operations we made, like so:

[image: PRODUCTS EXAMPLE QUERY RESULTS]

Comment: I would personally use UPPER CASE for the keywords; however that is likely to start a holy war, so perhaps not.

Comment: When defining primary keys, unique constraints etc, you probably should specify the name of the constraint.

Comment: Depending on the SQL version you might want to read up on [datetime2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and what max said is somewhat consensus. At least you got the semicolon right

Comment: Oh god @Phrancis! Why did you prefix all of the fields with an abbreviation of their table name?! *Why?* Maybe it's just a pet peeve of mine, but I find it terribly redundant. Of course, you were consistent, so that counts for something at least.

Comment: @RubberDuck I could lie and say that I thought it was a good practice, but the reality of it is that it is what I'm used to at work, and I wrote this to teach to a friend who wanted to apply. But yes I agree, it seems redundant. On the flip side, at least it makes table aliasing easy lol.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Also said before, but I think it worth mentioning again: there is not need for prefix_ for all columns. As far as I know, [Hungarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Notable_opinions) and [Leszynski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leszynski_naming_convention) notations are not exactly recommended. Since column names are almost always used in conjunction with their table, the table alias will make the reader known the table for a column.
2. It's a matter of taste, but instead of all-caps table (and other object names), I would use CamelCase identifiers. They are easier to read, more compact (on variable length fonts) and are more friendlier with ORMs (e.g. Entity Framework).
3. Triggers - I know they are part of the language, but I would avoid using for a basic course. I would find defaults more appropriate. Triggers are very tricky objects that should be avoided in most cases, as they: can create various hard to debug side effects, can raise performance problems, are ones of the last objects to look for when looking for the root cause of a problem.
4. Transactions containing a single DML operations: DML operations act as an atomic operation (all or none values are changes), so there is not need for `BEGIN` / `COMMIT TRAN`. Illustrating transactions should contain several operations. Also playing with `SET XACT_ABORT` option is a good idea, as its default value is `OFF` and some errors may leave the transaction un-aborted (and this can get really ugly, as it might block other SPIDs!)
5. Mark dev completed and add the product from dev to catalog: besides provided code, a `MERGE` example will be fit. The same thing could be done elegantly using a `MERGE`, thus having a single statement that executes atomically.
6. (Advanced) Faster delete: after the last `DELETE` statement, you can also show how to avoid using `%` at the beginning of the token and getting a full scan of the table:

   - Having a separated column for the actual user name, that is populated when a record in inserted.

   OR

   - Adding a persisted computed column in table `PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_CATALOG` that gets the actual user name

     - Creating an index for this column
     - Performing `DELETE` using this column

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first answer.

Comment: @Alexei very good answer and lots of great points!